# installing a windows service with .exe path in c#

Tags: c#, service, installutil

I need to install a service programatically (It even can be done with InstallUtil but it can't be done manually)

I have the following code but can't figure out how to do it properly since that code asks for some class info wich I dont know and I need to know how to use it in order to execute it using teh .exe.
The code is as follows:

```
public static void InstallService(string ExeFilename)
{
    System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller Installer = new System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller(ExeFilename,null);
    Installer.UseNewContext = true;
    Installer.Install(null);
    Installer.Commit(null);
}
```

Comment: Does the service receive parameters?

Comment: This code works with a simple windows service i've. What's the problem?

Comment: System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller Installer = new System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller(ExeFilename,null);
that null represents what? cause it says something about a command line.
I need this to work with the path to the .exe of the service

Comment: It gives you an error? What error?
That null means that you aren't passing commands.

Comment: I have to debug the whole thing in order to check the paths and functions. Once I get to that funcion I will post the message it gives me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void InstallService(string ExeFilename)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller Installer = new System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller(ExeFilename, null);
                Installer.UseNewContext = true;
                Installer.Install(null);
                Installer.Commit(null);
                DialogResult NovoDialog = new DialogResult();
                NovoDialog = MessageBox.Show("Deseja Iniciar o Serviço?", "Orca ++ Updater", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (NovoDialog == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    ServiceController service = new ServiceController("OrcaService");
                    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500);
                    service.Start();
                    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Erro NovoErro = new Erro();
                Program.Erro = ex.ToString();
                NovoErro.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

This is how I solveed it

Comment: Hello, I tried the same but AssemblyInstaller(string, string[]) accept only .dll file path which causing I cannot start a WinService when it's not an .exe. But when I insert there an path with suffix .exe, I receive BadFormatImageException. Do you please know how to fix ?